# Firestore query documents according to Boolean values. Only friend Posts

Tags: angular, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with an array of booleans of the type:

```
Friend01ID: True
Friend02ID: True
Friend03ID: True
```

I also have a collection with the IDs and documents of the posts:

```
Posts - FriendID - AllPosts - [array with all posts]
```

How could I make an appointment so that it was possible only to view the posts of friends?